# How to use the character array to identify a string

Tags: c

For my class we use char arrays for strings. If I was to use an `if else` statement, would something like this work if I had it modified to do so?

I know an array like this would make every character broken down to simple letters. And to use an `if else` statement I have to go like array[1] == 'H' and so on.

Is there a way to modify the code below to spit out the information I want if I type up "Alas". Right now, it only goes to the `else` part.

```
int main()
{
    char s[10];

    printf("Yo, this is a string: ");
    gets_s(s);

    if (s == "Alas")
    {
        printf("B ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A");
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
int main()
{
    char s[10];

    printf("Yo, this is a string: ");
    gets_s(s);

    if (strcmp(s, "Alas") == 0)
    {
        printf("B ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A");
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncmp.html#tag_16_579) standard library function to compare two strings. Include the `<string.h>` header.

```
strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
```

#### RETURN VALUE:

> Upon successful completion, `strncmp()` shall return an integer greater than, equal to, or less than 0, if the possibly null-terminated array pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the possibly null-terminated array pointed to by `s2` respectively.

Comment: What reasoning leads you to recommend `strncmp` over `strcmp`?

Comment: @Jongware; I can say this is a smart question :). My answer is :`The strncmp function compares not more than n characters (characters that follow a null character are not compared) from the array pointed to by s1 to the array pointed to
by s2.`, unlike `strcmp`. But to be honest, **none of them is safe to use**.

Comment: Now this is what happen when you really want to be honest but do not want to spoon feed :(

Comment: A code-only answer, and it got accepted as "the" answer. *Quelle surprise.*

Comment: I personally don't like the use of both `strncmp` and `strcmp` for simple equality comparison of two strings, since it requires the inclusion of a library, plus they do more than what the user needs. But both this and the accepted answer use them, in which case this answer would be more appropriate to be ***the*** answer over the other code-only version.

Comment: I also do not prefer but using both `strncmp` with some caution is not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Now in your code s is pointer and "Alas" is treated as pointer. Pointer to another memory area. This is a reason why they are always different. Use

```
if (!strcmp(s, "Alas"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to know is whether two strings are identical or not, you can define a function yourself to check each character of two strings, returning a `0` as soon as you encounter a difference, returning a `1` only if it encounters the terminating zero on both at the same time:

```
SameStrings( char * s1, char * s2 ) {
    for ( int i = 0; s1[i] && s2[i]; i++ )
        if ( s1[i] != s2[i] )
            return 0;

    // if the programme advanced this far
    // either one of both should be 0
    return s1[i] == s2[i];

    // if they are equal, then both must be 0, in which case it will return 1
    // else it will return a 0
}
```

You can add one more argument to that function, an integer that will limit the maximum number of characters to be checked, in case, for example, you want `SameStrings( "lalaqwe", "lalaasd", 4 )` to return true.

This is good if you don't want to include a library for a function that does much more than you need...